# Is it possible to post system exception in the culture of my choice?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

For example, my asp.net application has a user which has an account number, name, address and a culture.

I know exceptions should rarely be shown to the user.

But lets say I do want to use this **framework exception** message localized, is it possible?

something like

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.ShowLocalizedMessage(myCurrentUser.CurrentCulture)
}
```

Comment: I think you should stop yourself at: "I know exceptions should rarely be shown to the user."

Comment: But lets say I do want to use this framework exception message localized, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framework exceptions will always be localized using the current thread's CurrentUICulture.  If you change the property on the thread, the exception messages will follow.  (This is usually seen as [more of a problem than a benefit](http://msmvps.com/blogs/calinoiu/archive/2006/06/30/103426.aspx), but ymmv...)

Comment: ok, now we know which culture it uses, now a culture is a culture, my user's is just as valid, anyway I can use his? Is a .net session always a thread, what I want to make sure is that im not passing something already built in?

Comment: The easiest way to use the client culture is to set the value of the uiCulture attribute of the globalization element to "auto" in your web.config file.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx)